# Try to return previous view from new opened window in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 appliaction and suppose I opened a new window using window.open through javascript and in this window I opened a new view. Now I want to go back to my previous view (from where I opened new window) with some data from opened window.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: You can pass the previous Url as a querystring parameter when you are calling window.open. YOu can then use the querystring paramter to redirect back to the previous page.

Comment: Yes I can but I want to render a partial view with returned data

Answer (score 0):

As long as you create a new window in your JS code, you get back a window handle.
If you don't navigate to an external URL, this handle allows you to fully control the window, including its HTML content:

```
var whandle = window.open("about:blank", "", "_blank");
whandle.document.write(yourhtml);
```

So, you can take some data from your existing page using jQuery and copy it as a new document to your child window.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, Actually I am navigating to an external url and that url returns back a url that is related to my project and it opens in new window itself.